# Insert values on Windows Dialog from Delphi Dialog

Tags: delphi, winapi, dialog, pascal

[image]

I want to know if there's a way to insert, for example, a FilePath in a DialogBox opened by Windows itself, but inserted from a Delphi variable to the Windows Dialog? Something like, click on an Upload button in any website that does open the File Explorer Dialog, and in Delphi send the value of the Path to the File Explorer of Website.

PS : I already have the code to get his `HWND` handle.

I don't know if this is possible, or is there's a way to do it.

**Edit** : A Select File from the site, what I want is simply to input the FilePath of this site by an app variable in Delphi.

Comment: You want to _customize_ i.e. the "Open" or "Select folder" dialog? As in [Custom preview for open dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2204706/4299358) and [File Open Dialog with Encodings combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1076827/4299358)? That differs per dialog. Add a screenshot to your question of the dialog in question with a painted button/control of your choice to make things more clear.

Comment: I want insert the PathFile of the Windows Dialog from Delphi application, but not an Dialog opened by Delphi App, only by whatever opens a Select Folder/File

Comment: My main purpose is related with WebScrapping using Web Driver.  But I got to a part where I'm not able to pass the file to the site's upload input, it's asynchronous and out of scope, I don't have access permission, but as the site upload opens the select file, the only way I thought it was to get the file locally with an Open Dialog and send it to the Select File site, which is a Windows Dialog, a workaround but...

Comment: You are looking for UIAutomation

Answer (score -2, accepted):

## Variants

If you know that dialog window's handle already then there are at least 2 variants:

1. finding the control by going through the children hierarchy, using [`FindWindowEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowexa)
2. relying on the dialog template's IDs, using [`GetDlgItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem)

Both may work out great, but are at the same time fragile, since the dialog window's structure (as per its controls and IDs) can change even by Service Packs already, let alone entire *Windows* versions. My experience here is from *Win2000* up to *Win7* and on those systems it worked.

## Dialog versions

What you posted as screenshot is the "*Vista*" version of the dialog; [the older "*Win95*" version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3885245/4299358) is identical in terms of accessing the "filename" ComboBox.

The old one is typical for having the buttons ("open" and "cancel") in one **row**. Older software might still use these, but your web browser most likely not:
[image: "Open" dialog window, Win95 version]

The one since *Vista* has its buttons in one **line** and is notable of featuring a full folder pane:
[image: "Open" dialog window, Vista version]

But both pictures show that the control layout is the same: a `ComboBoxEx32` is a direct child of the window, having its own child(s). So we can use the same code for both versions.

## Code

```delphi
var
  hDialog, hCbx32, hCbx, hEdit, hFilename: HWND;
  sText: String;
begin
  hDialog:= 9568854;  // Dialog window, class "32770"
  sText:= 'M:\my\filename.ext';  // What should be set

  // Variant #1: finding the control by parents and childs.
  // Luckily both the old dialog up to XP and the new dialog
  // since Vista do not differ as per the filename ComboBox.
  hCbx32:= FindWindowEx( hDialog, 0, 'ComboBoxEx32', nil );  // Most likely the 3rd child control
  hCbx:=   FindWindowEx( hCbx32,  0, 'ComboBox',     nil );  // Actual ComboBox inside that
  hEdit:=  FindWindowEx( hCbx,    0, 'Edit',         nil );  // Edit control inside ComboBox
  SendMessage( hEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, LPARAM(PChar(sText)) );

  // Variant #2: using dialog template IDs, which haven't
  // changed since XP with one of its Service Packs. However,
  // tested with Win7 only.
  hFilename:= GetDlgItem( hDialog, $47C );  // "cmb13", found at least in XP SP3
  if hFilename= 0 then hFilename:= GetDlgItem( hDialog, $480 );  // "edt1" = Maybe prior to XP without any SP
  SendMessage( hFilename, WM_SETTEXT, 0, LPARAM(PChar(sText)) );
end;
```

One of both variants should do already. Successfully tested on *Win7x64*

- using *Paint*'s "Open" command for the *Vista* dialog version, and
- one of my older program's "Open" command for the *Win95* dialog version:

the text in the filename's ComboBox was set as expected.